# the reasonable way synchronize data between mongodb and redis?

Tags: mongodb, redis

I am developing a distributed IM system. I use Redis and Mongo to store IM data. In this scenario Redis is used for cache and Mongo for data storage. I want to synchronize data from Mongo to Redis when origin data was changed by an admin system. I'm wondering if it possible for me to listen for events on Mongo like SaveOrUpdateEventListener in Hibernate done?

Could someone tell me what the best way to solve this problem? Thanks!